# Clicking on Publish button in main window doesn't work after switching from pop up window in WebDriver

Tags: java, popup, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code to add a photo at pop up window and then do a click on PUBLISH button at main window after returning from pop up window:

//I am in main window now:

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Photo")).click();//Add Photo link
driver.switchTo().window("uploadPhoto");
```

I have transitted to pop up window:

```
elemById("widget_129_upload_file").sendKeys("F:\\Blossom.jpg");//Browsing a .jpg file
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.button.submit")).click();//this is UPLOAD button at pop up window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
```

I am back at main window again:

```
elemByCssSelector("input[value=Publish]").click();//Publish button at main window WHICH IS NOT BEING CLICKED
```

Unfortunately, Publish button at main window doesn't work. There is no error and selenium test is stopped. What's the wrong in my code? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The same way mentioned in my question is working well when there is no matter of uploading photo at pop up window:

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window("Add Placement");//switch to pop up window
```

//in pop up window: fill up some text fields and click Submit button
//The following code for switching to main window

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
```

//The following line of code is an assertion in main window

```
assertTrue(isTextPresent("placementname:WWW"), "placement is not created");
```

So, my guess is that as it took long time to upload photo at pop up window after returning to main window test execution is being stopped